# Output screen show the totally white , nothing output are comming

Tags: javascript, reactjs, resultset, windward

i want to get the output on  this code.

when m try to run this code this shows  only a white screen doesn't know why

m putting the code here

```
// first page  find the code easliy App main page this is. 

import React {} from react;
import About from './component/About';
import Navbar from './component/Navbar';
import TextFrom from './component/TextFrom';
import {
  BrowserRouter,
   Router,
   Route,
   Routes,
} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState('light');//wheather dark mode is enabled or not
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState({
    msg: "",
    type: ""
  });
  // we define a setalert methode for pass the value//
  const showAlert = (message, type) => { 
    setAlert({
      msg: message,
      type: type
    }) //here Alert is a object
    setTimeout(() => {
      setAlert(null);
    }, 1500);

  }
  const toggleMode = () => {
    if (mode === 'light') {
      setMode('dark')
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#14142c';
      showAlert("Dark modeis enabled", "success");
      document.title = 'TextUtils-Dark Mode';
      // setInterval(()=>{
      //   document.title="TextUtils is Good"
      // },3000);
      // setInterval(()=>{
      //   document.title="Done By Ali"
      // },1000);
    }
    else {
      setMode('light')
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
      showAlert("light mode  is enabled", "success");
      document.title = 'TextUtils-Light Mode';
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Router> 
      <Navbar title="TextUtils" mode={mode} toggleMode={toggleMode} />
      <Alert alert={alert} />
      <div className="container my-3">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <TextFrom showAlert={showAlert} heading="enter the text value" mode={mode} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
      </Router>
      </BrowserRouter> 
    </>
  );
}


export default App;

//Page seond also m puthing here//
this show only error in this page
import React from 'react'
import { PropTypes } from "prop-types";


export default function Navbar(props) {

  return (

<nav className={`navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-${props.mode} bg-${props.mode}`}>
  <div className="container-fluid text-white">
    <a className="navbar-brand" href="/"  >{props.title}</a>
    <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li className="nav-item " >
          <a className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item " >
          <a className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">About</a>
         </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <a className="nav-link" href="/">{props.aboutText} </a>
        </li>
       </ul>
      <form className="d-flex">
        <input className="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" />
        <button className="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
      <div className={`form-check form-switch text-${props.mode==='light'?'dark':'light'}`}>
      <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault"onClick={props.toggleMode}/>
      <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="flexSwitchCheckDefault" >Enable the Dark Mode</label>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  )
}

Navbar.propTypes = { title:PropTypes.string.isRequired,
                    aboutText:PropTypes.string.isRequired  
                    
                  }
Navbar.dafaultProps ={
                  title:'Set title  here',
                  aboutText:'about text here '
}
```

please check the given code don't know why it not working  when m ran this website code in visual studio  then ran successfully  and showed a message in the console. window but when m open the browser then its nothing shows on the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

You are using react-router wrongly. Have another look at the documentation
https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial

I have provided a working example using your code, with some comments about what was incorrect. See here.

https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-sun-q4ctsh?file=/src/App.js

Comment: still not working same issue is coming  full screen blank

Comment: I can't help you any further, the sandbox I linked worked. You can create a new question or update this one with your new code. Try to include any errors, escpecially any from the web dev console.